# Segmentation Fault Catch

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, signals, multiprocessing, maya

I have a python script and it will loop through bunch of maya files and do some stuff. But some time maya get seg fault and my script will stop there. I tried with `signal` and `multiprocess`. But both failed.

```
import os, optparse, glob, json, signal
import maya.standalone
import maya.cmds as cmds
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def loadMayaBd():
    maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')

def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    print "segfault"

def doSome(args, options):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, sig_handler)
    loadMayaBd()
    #from here its just a example
    fileNameList = args[0]
    for eachFile in fileNameList:
        #this is throwing the seg fault
        #I want continue my for llop even if there is any segfault
        #I don't want to exit python coz of that segfault
        cmds.file(eachFile, force = 1, open = 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] args(file list)"
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-l", "--log", dest="log",
                  help="Log File Path", metavar="LOG_FILE")
    parser.add_option("-v", "--verbose", dest="verbose",
                  help="Print All Logs", metavar="VERBOSE", default=False, action='store_true')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) <= 0:
        errorMsg = "You must pass file path list for crawling"
        raise RuntimeError(errorMsg)
    p = Process(target=doSome, args=(args, options))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Is there any other method which can trap seg fault and continue with next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using "try" to avoiding a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950296/using-try-to-avoiding-a-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```py
import os
import signal


def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    print("segfault")


signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, sig_handler)

os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGSEGV)

while True:
    pass
```

Are you sure you are trapping the segfault in each process that you are spawning?

Comment: Question edited. No I don't think so I am catching each process :(

Comment: Move `signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, sig_handler)` to inside your startCrawling method. It doesn't look like you are setting a trap on each process.

Comment: Thanks man, checking that and it will take some time :). I will update you

Comment: @achayan how did it go? I'm stuck on a similar issue.